# Where can I find an overview of Bitcoin exchange APIs?

Tags: exchanges, api, currencies, bots

Where can I find information on a large number of "exchange" or "trading platform" APIs showing which currencies (digital and fiat) they convert between?

Comment: Hi user41634,
I just edited your question's title in order to better capture the question's intent. Should you disagree with what I did, feel free to change it to your liking or rollback. The second part of your question seemed fairly unrelated, so I removed it, to give your question a clear focus. If you can think of how to ask that without inviting discussion as it was before, you might want to ask that as a new separate question.

Answer (score 6):

Since you originally stated that you wanted to write a trading bot, perhaps you will find the following library useful:

"[**XChange**](https://github.com/timmolter/XChange) is a Java library providing a simple and consistent API for interacting with over a dozen Bitcoin exchanges providing a consistent interface for trading and accessing market data" (according to their [GitHub page](https://github.com/timmolter/XChange))

Unfortunately, I cannot tell you more about it, as I just stumbled upon it by accident.

Answer (score 4):

Each site has its own set of apis and documentation, I don't think it's likely that you'll find a single site with a complete set of APIs.

Here are some links to get you started:

- coinbase.com/api/doc

Comment: Are such APIs for free?

Comment: The API is usually free (I am looking into Coinbase/GDAX), but you are charged a fee at every trade. Also note, some of the above are N/A any more...

Comment: Multiple links have been removed because they were linking to broken or domain parking services. Please consider adding new links to make this answer more useful.